# using html select tag in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I use following Html Tag in my Asp.net source code I encounter this error message:

```
 <select runat="server" onchange="showcity();" class="textbox" id="DpCity" name="DpCity">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">unknown</option>
 </select>
```

**Error message in runtime:**

```
DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect' does not contain a property with the name 'SelectedValue'.
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I think problem is somewhere in codebehind where control is populated with values.

Comment: show the DataBind() code for the HtmlSelect. Also can you explain why you used HtmlSelect instead of asp:DropDownList? Because we might be able to change that back to asp:DropDownList.

Comment: thanks for your attention. I solved My problem, I was used DpCity.selectedValue in one of my datasources  while Dpcity is a Html Tag. I deletd it so my problem solved

Comment: The html looks fine. Can you check if you are accessing the SelectedValue property in code behind in any event.  If you do, then change it to SelectedItem.Value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SelectedValue is not a property of a Select control. Select is different than DropDownList. To get the selected value of the Select list, use this code:

```
var selectedValue = DpCity.Value;
```